# How sync `Build-Version` in manifest.fm jar file and maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest.mf

Maven has `SNAPSHOT` which is resolved **only** when jar is deployed into repository. But manifest.fm contains `Build-Version`, which should be resolved during build time. E.g. when jar published there will be a gap between jar version and `Build-Version`. How to solve this?

Btw, can it be that `Build-Version` in manifest files is outdated?

Comment: I fear your question is too broad ...

Comment: You need to find the definition of `Release-Version` and `Build-Version` from your workplace standard practices.

Comment: question was rewritten.

Comment: As you said, the exact timestamp version of a SNAPSHOT artifact is only known _after_ the deployment. So there is no way to put it into the `manifest.mf`. What is the purpose of "Build-Version"?